# random walk across 10x10 grid array

Tags: java

The purpose of this program is to build a 10x10 array grid made out of periods (.), allow the user to designate a starting point, and then the program will randomly choose numbers which are assigned to directions for the 'walker' to go. Each time it moves it marks its spot with the next letter in the alphabet (the starting point is marked by A). I haven't done this part yet but I know how I will; if the walker crosses out of the bounds of the array (AKA > 10 or < 0) it will say "you were arrested" and if the variable alpha == 'Z' it way say "You made it home".

The main problem as far as I can tell is with the method processing(), where I draw numbers from getRand (which I have confirmed is working) and then assign them directions which are given to the array. But for some reason when it prints the grid it only shows the starting point, and not the movement of the walker.

Another question I have of lesser importance is if there is a more brief way to display my grid than how I have been (A massive brick of text in a System.out.print)

```
    package walktester;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DrunkWalker {
    private char[][] walkgrid = new char[10][10];
    private static int randNSEW;
    private int randomnum;
    private int startrow;
    private int startcol;
    private char alpha = 'A';
    private int nextrow;
    private int nextcol;

    public DrunkWalker(int r, int c) {
        startrow = r;
        startcol = c;
        nextrow = startrow;
        nextcol = startcol;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                walkgrid[i][j] = '.';
        }
        walkgrid[r][c] = alpha;
    }

    public static void getRand(){
        int x100 = 0;
        double randomNum = 0.0;
    randomNum = Math.random();
    x100 = (int) (randomNum * 100);
    randNSEW = x100 % 4;
}

public int getNextRow(){
    return nextrow;
}

public int getNextCol(){
    return nextcol;
}

public void processing(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i ++){
    getRand();
    if(randNSEW == 0){
        nextcol--;
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    if(randNSEW == 1){
        nextrow++;
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    if(randNSEW == 2){
        nextcol++;
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    if(randNSEW == 3){
        nextrow--;
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    }
}



public char[][] DisplayGrid() {
    System.out.print(
            walkgrid[0][0] + " " + walkgrid[0][1] + " " + walkgrid[0][2] + " " + walkgrid[0][3] + " " + walkgrid[0][4] + " " + walkgrid[0][5] + " " + walkgrid[0][6] + " " + walkgrid[0][7] + " " + walkgrid[0][8] + " " + walkgrid[0][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[1][0] + " " + walkgrid[1][1] + " " + walkgrid[1][2] + " " + walkgrid[1][3] + " " + walkgrid[1][4] + " " + walkgrid[1][5] + " " + walkgrid[1][6] + " " + walkgrid[1][7] + " " + walkgrid[1][8] + " " + walkgrid[1][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[2][0] + " " + walkgrid[2][1] + " " + walkgrid[2][2] + " " + walkgrid[2][3] + " " + walkgrid[2][4] + " " + walkgrid[2][5] + " " + walkgrid[2][6] + " " + walkgrid[2][7] + " " + walkgrid[2][8] + " " + walkgrid[2][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[3][0] + " " + walkgrid[3][1] + " " + walkgrid[3][2] + " " + walkgrid[3][3] + " " + walkgrid[3][4] + " " + walkgrid[3][5] + " " + walkgrid[3][6] + " " + walkgrid[3][7] + " " + walkgrid[3][8] + " " + walkgrid[3][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[4][0] + " " + walkgrid[4][1] + " " + walkgrid[4][2] + " " + walkgrid[4][3] + " " + walkgrid[4][4] + " " + walkgrid[4][5] + " " + walkgrid[4][6] + " " + walkgrid[4][7] + " " + walkgrid[4][8] + " " + walkgrid[4][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[5][0] + " " + walkgrid[5][1] + " " + walkgrid[5][2] + " " + walkgrid[5][3] + " " + walkgrid[5][4] + " " + walkgrid[5][5] + " " + walkgrid[5][6] + " " + walkgrid[5][7] + " " + walkgrid[5][8] + " " + walkgrid[5][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[6][0] + " " + walkgrid[6][1] + " " + walkgrid[6][2] + " " + walkgrid[6][3] + " " + walkgrid[6][4] + " " + walkgrid[6][5] + " " + walkgrid[6][6] + " " + walkgrid[6][7] + " " + walkgrid[6][8] + " " + walkgrid[6][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[7][0] + " " + walkgrid[7][1] + " " + walkgrid[7][2] + " " + walkgrid[7][3] + " " + walkgrid[7][4] + " " + walkgrid[7][5] + " " + walkgrid[7][6] + " " + walkgrid[7][7] + " " + walkgrid[7][8] + " " + walkgrid[7][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[8][0] + " " + walkgrid[8][1] + " " + walkgrid[8][2] + " " + walkgrid[8][3] + " " + walkgrid[8][4] + " " + walkgrid[8][5] + " " + walkgrid[8][6] + " " + walkgrid[8][7] + " " + walkgrid[8][8] + " " + walkgrid[8][9] + "\n" + 
            walkgrid[9][0] + " " + walkgrid[9][1] + " " + walkgrid[9][2] + " " + walkgrid[9][3] + " " + walkgrid[9][4] + " " + walkgrid[9][5] + " " + walkgrid[9][6] + " " + walkgrid[9][7] + " " + walkgrid[9][8] + " " + walkgrid[9][9] + "\n"
    );
    return walkgrid;
    }
}

public class WalkTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inpr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inpc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inpchoice = new Scanner(System.in);

    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char choice = 'y';

    while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') {
        System.out.println("Please enter x coordinate between 1 and 10.");
        r = inpr.nextInt();
        r = r - 1;

        System.out.println("Please enter y coordinate between 1 and 10");
        c = inpr.nextInt();
        c = c - 1;

        if(r < 0 || r > 9 || c < 0 || c > 9){
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
            choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                continue;
            }
            else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        DrunkWalker drunkwalker = new DrunkWalker(r, c);
        drunkwalker.DisplayGrid();

        System.out.println("Restart? y/n");
        choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
        if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
            continue;
        }
        else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
            choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
        }


       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DisplayGrid()` method should be a double-nested for loop. :) Avoid magic numbers. Your program should specify the dimensions of the grid i.e. height and width and those should be used.

Comment: See loop here: http://pastebin.com/2ZfjmSEA

Answer (score 3):

The code that moves the walker is in a method called `processing()`, but you never call it.

You can make your `DisplayGrid()` method simpler (and it will still print the same stuff):

```
public char[][] DisplayGrid() {
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.print(walkgrid[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return walkgrid;
}
```

Your `processing()` method needs to check if the walker leaves the bounds of the area. If you don't, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public boolean processing(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i ++){
        getRand();
        if(randNSEW == 0){
            nextcol--;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 1){
            nextrow++;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 2){
            nextcol++;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 3){
            nextrow--;
        }

        if(nextrow < 0 || nextrow >= 10 || nextcol < 0 || nextcol >= 10) {
            return false;
        }

        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you need to call `processing()` and check the return value to see if the walker succeeded:

```
DrunkWalker drunkwalker = new DrunkWalker(r, c);
boolean walkerSucceeded = drunkwalker.processing();
drunkwalker.DisplayGrid();
if(walkerSucceeded) {
    System.out.println("You made it home");
} else {
    System.out.println("You were arrested");
}
```

And keep in mind (as you will see when you test this), that the walker can cross their own tracks (so you might see some letters missing).

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. Is there any good way to avoid going where it has already been?

Comment: You could check if the `walkgrid` contains a '.' at the future location, and if so, it could either return false to say you're arrested, or it could choose another direction. You'd need to test if you had walked yourself into a dead-end at which point you would need to find a way for the method to exit.

Comment: What I need is if it finds that the space has already been visited, it tries the next spot and so on